# jquery fix div on the top while scrolling

Tags: jquery

Can somebody have a look at code below?

http://jsfiddle.net/PeterPark/xC2YH/

html:

```
<div id="wrap">
            <header>
                <div id="fixitattop">
                    <hr><h1>It's me</h1><hr>
                    <div id="nav">
                        <a href="#">Menu1</a> / <a href="#">Menu2</a>
                    </div>
                    <hr>  
                </div>  
            </header>

            <div class="main">
                <div class="project1"></div>
                <div class="project2"></div>
                <div class="project3"></div>
                <div class="project4"></div>
                <div class="project5"></div>
                <div class="project6"></div>
            </div>

            <footer>
                <p>

                </p>
            </footer>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(fixHeader);
    fixHeader();


});

function fixHeader (){
    var $fixit = $('#fixitattop');
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 100){
        $fixit.css({
            'position':'fixed',
            'top':'2px'

        });
    } else {
        $fixit.css({
            'position':'relative',
            'top':'auto'
        });
    }
}
```

I would like to fix `fixitattop` div and its subcontents on the top while scrolling but when `position` changes to "fixed", it gets ugly. Can somebody let me know a fix for this?

Comment: Thanks to all of you. it works great now. 
Now I am having a bit of issue when scrolling down. when it fixes it eats up some height so it seems it skips some contents on a div below of it. Please see a site below. having the exact same issue. 
Any workarounds on this?
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/

Answer (score 0):

Just set a width to #fixitattop, not just max-width; I suggest making it width:100%; and letting max-width handle limiting it to 1000px;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$fixit.css({
    'position':'fixed',
    'top':'2px',
    'padding' : '0px',
    'width' : '100%'

});
```

You have to specify the width of the element and delete the padding since you don't need it in a top fixed bar.

Answer (score 0):

For fixed elements you must assume that its percent size is based on window size. So if you want to have it full-page but no more than 1000px width max, you have to tell him this like that:

```
#fixitattop {
    position : relative;
    width: 100%; /*IMPORTANT*/
    max-width: 1000px; /*IMPORTANT*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20% 10%;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xC2YH/1/)

Sorry for poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `width: 80%;` in your `script` when scrolled. Yeah `80%`, why not `100%`? because in your `css`, you've just set the `#fixitattop` padding to `20% 10%` meaning `20%` to `top`, `20%` to `bottom`, `10% left` and `10% right`. Well the only concern is the `left` and the `right` since you have to change only the `width` of your `div` so then you can now do the math. `100% - (10%+10%) = 80%`. Here's your [**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xC2YH/32/) btw. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Note: I'd also re-place your `<hr>` to a nicest place.